# How to mount ceph fs with Microceph?

Tags: snap, ceph

I follow the steps from https://snapcraft.io/microceph
and demo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PX1n3ZAWuAU
but now i'm not sure how to mount with microceph cephfs?

(Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 1):

As I also tried microceph instead of ceph on my 3 nodes, I have to mount CEPHFs on my nodes.
I just finished it, and I hope I found an answer :

- On one of your nodes :

  - create fs (pools, metadata...) with this command : `sudo microceph.ceph fs volume create data`
- On all nodes :

  - (this is curious but I get errors without it) `sudo apt install ceph-commmon`
  - Create a directory where to mount your fs (`/var/data` for example) : `mkdir /var/data`
  - Let's create links to help system to find snap microceph:

    - `sudo ln -sf /var/snap/microceph/current/conf/ceph.client.admin.keyring /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring`
    - `sudo ln -sf /var/snap/microceph/current/conf/ceph.keyring /etc/ceph/ceph.keyring`
    - `sudo ln -sf /var/snap/microceph/current/conf/ceph.conf /etc/ceph/ceph.conf`

- Edit `/etc/fstab` file (be careful with this file :) ); add this (you have to choose correct node names) :
  `node1,node2,node3:/ /var/data ceph name=admin,noatime,_netdev 0 0`
- Let's mount fs : `sudo mount -a`

I hope my answer will help you :)